# automated tool to check branches for conflicts in git

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

We using feature branches and I'm looking for a tool that monitors branches for conflicts?  I know this is a reason for us to be use main-based development with feature switches, but that not an option in the short term.

The situation is we have a DEV branch and two feature branches (A and B) which have some overlap and are modifying the same systems/files.

The current flow is: we merge A into DEV, then merge DEV into B, deal with conflicts, then merge B into DEV.

We're trying to minimize the conflicts that are happening between A and B.  Often the features are unrelated and there are not conflicts. But when there are (modifying the same lines) or potential merge problems (e.g., both touching the same file) I would like to have some report to alert us about it to make sure that Team A and Team B work more closely together to minimize or avoid the conflicts.

Does anyone know of a tool or process to effectively deal with this?

Comment: I used to think i could get away with not having a master branch. My suggestion? Manually merge your branches this one last time before switching to a master branch system. Trust me, I've seen both sides, and without a master branch, you will waste a lot of precious time and energy. You will save far more time by making that switch now than you'll ever save trying to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool that do just what you want: it parses `git diff` output and searches for conflicts between branches (generally speaking, between treeishes).

It is written in python3 and can be obtained from PYPI: `pip3 install gitconflict`.

Usage:

```
git conflict A B DEV
```

Prints first found conflict between given treeishes.
Returns 1 if no conflicts found, 0 otherwise.

Limitations:

- it doesn't detect binary file conflicts
- may produce false positives in some cases (tool warns you that there is a conflict but git will merge w/o conflict or auto-resolve it)